# Nested (multiple) string interpolation in PHP

Tags: php, string, string-interpolation

If I have a variable that contains nested variables, e.g.:

```
$message = "Hello $user_name, an email was send to $user_email ...";
$user_name = 'User Name';
$user_email = 'user@email.com';
```

is it possible to produce an output such as:

```
Hello User Name, an email was send to user@email.com ...
```

without calling `eval()`?

Comment: I don't think so, the variables are not defined when you build the string `$message`.

Comment: Be sure, PHP is interpreter language, it's executing line by line with top-down approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can 'define' placeholders and replace it where you need it.

```
$message = "Hello #user_name#, an email was send to #user_email# ...";
$user_name = 'User Name';
$user_email = 'user@email.com';

$newMessage = str_replace(array("#user_name#", "#user_email#"), array($user_name, $user_email), $message);
```

See [str_replace](https://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible just place the variables `$user_email` and `$user_name` above `$message` so they become instantiated first.

```
$user_email = 'user@email.com';
$user_name = 'User Name';
$message = "Hello $user_name, an email was send to $user_email ...";

echo $message; //Will output: Hello User Name, an email was send to user@email.com ...
```

EDIT: After reading your reaction you could use a closure for example:

```
$message = function($name = null, $email = null){
  return "Hello $name, an email was send to $email ...";
};

$user_name = 'User Name';
$user_email = 'user@email.com';

$newMessage = $message($user_name, $user_email);
```

Comment: The case is that when I build the variable $message the nested variables are not defined yet. $user_name and $user_email are only placeholders.

Comment: How exactly do you mean can you provide some sample code?

Comment: For example the content of the $message could come from a DB record and later on it will be displayed when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [printf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) function:

```
$message = "Hello %s, an email was send to %s ...";
$user_name = 'User Name';
$user_email = 'user@email.com';

echo sprintf($message, $user_name, $user_email);
```

or

```
printf($message, $user_name, $user_email);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$user_email = 'user@email.com';
$user_name = 'User Name';
$message = "Hello " . $user_name . ", an email was send to " . $user_email . " ...";
```